# Flutter screen change callback

Tags: mobile, flutter

I want to get a callback when the screen is changed, so I can stop my recurring request that runs on that specific screen. “dispose” is only called when Navigator.pop is used, but not when Navigator.push is called. Is there a way to detect that the screen is changed and not being shown at the moment?

Comment: What do you mean by "screen is changed"?

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815014/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-flutter/50815335#50815335 ?

Comment: I mean like navigating to a new route with Navigator.push or Navigator.pop. For pop it works as i want it, dispose method is called, but for push, it is not called.

Comment: `initState()` of the new page should be called when you navigate to it. Still not sure what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Is your flow like: #1 Start Recurring task on screen 1; #2 Push to Screen 2; #3 do some activity on screen 2; #4 on pop of screen 2 dispose the recurring task of screen 1? If yes, then you can future handle of push in screen 1. Complete of future is called on pop of screen 2

Comment: I have one screen where every 10 seconds I am sending a request to check the status of the trip. When you click some button on that screen it can open a map page, info page or ticket page. So what i want to do is, when user clicks any button to open a new screen, i want to be able to cancel the timer, so that it wont continue sending the request. Normally on Android for a Fragment, i would have canceled the timer on "onPaused", and restarted it on "onResume". I need something similar to that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Register a RouteObserver on your MaterialApp or WidgetsApp and make your stateful widget a RouteAware. Sample code here: [RouteObserver](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i needed!