# Detect if the user leaves the current page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to detect if the user leaves the current page?
I don’t think `WidgetsBinding` will work, because it handles these events by itself.
So, does anyone have any solution?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you might be looking for `willPopScope` widget. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635450/is-there-any-way-intercept-back-keydown-in-flutter-app-on-android

Answer (score 20):

I have an easy solution if by "leaving the page" you mean that the user goes "back" from this page. The following solution will not work if you also want to get notified if the user opens up another page in front of the current one.

For the first case, you could use a [WillPopScope](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html).
It's a class that notifies you when the enclosing `ModalRoute` (internally used by the `Navigator`) is about to be popped. It even leaves you a choice to whether or not you want the pop to happen.

Just wrap the second screen's `Scaffold` in a `WillPopScope`.

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    // You can do some work here.
    // Returning true allows the pop to happen, returning false prevents it.
    return true;
  },
  child: ... // Your Scaffold goes here.
);
```

Comment: WillPopScope() doesn't work for me at all.  No error, nothing.  With a ```print()``` before the ```return true;``` I confirmed it's not even reached.

Comment: I'm using the Navigator's push method to push my "second" page, and WillPopScope works great! If it does not work for you, is it possible that you are not using Flutter's built-in Navigator?

Comment: This one have a bug when use bottom sheet modal, it call when we drag down and drag up the modal without dismiss it

Answer (score 19):

As per your description i think that you want to track your user if user press back button or return to previous screen.

You can achieve this by overriding the `dispose` on your `State` class.

May Following example help you to figure out your solution.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: EventRow(),
    );
  }
}


class EventRow extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: new RaisedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
              );
              },
            child: Text("Goto Second Scrren"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}


class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    print("Back To old Screen");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container(
          child: new RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Goto First Scrren"),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly compared to WillPopScope()

Comment: It will work. but in some cases, if you're navigating too quickly it will take time to reflect as the dispose method calls.

Answer (score 17):

RouteObserver and RouteAware are the way to go if you want to detect if the user leaves the screen, no matter if it's by going back (popping) or pushing another context.

Here's an example. Sorry for it being it a bit long, if you try it and run it you'll realize that it's pretty simple.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  static final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver =
      RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Screen1(),
        'screen2': (context) => Screen2(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class ScreenWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Function() onLeaveScreen;
  final String routeName;
  ScreenWrapper({this.child, this.onLeaveScreen, @required this.routeName});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ScreenWrapperState();
  }
}

class ScreenWrapperState extends State<ScreenWrapper> with RouteAware {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }

  void onLeaveScreen() {
    if (widget.onLeaveScreen != null) {
      widget.onLeaveScreen();
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    App.routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    App.routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    print('*** Entering screen: ${widget.routeName}');
  }

  void didPushNext() {
    print('*** Leaving screen: ${widget.routeName}');
    onLeaveScreen();
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    print('*** Going back, leaving screen: ${widget.routeName}');
    onLeaveScreen();
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    print('*** Going back to screen: ${widget.routeName}');
  }
}

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenWrapper(
      onLeaveScreen: () {
        print("***** Here's my special handling for leaving screen1!!");
      },
      routeName: '/',
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('This is Screen1'),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Press here to go to screen 2'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'screen2');
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                    "Press here to go back (only works if you've pushed before)"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.maybePop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenWrapper(
      routeName: 'screen2',
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('This is Screen2'),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Press here to go to screen 1'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                    "Press here to go back (only works if you've pushed before)"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.maybePop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working well for detecting when the page is entered, but `didPop` does not run for some reason

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by overriding the `dispose()` method.

Comment: I use dispose, but it only called if we go back for example. If we open a new page, dispose is not called.

Answer (score 1):

I recently got into a situation where I needed to detect a change in route for both popping the current route or pushing to a new route from the current one and I was able to achieve that with [RouteObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html) gotten from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51341207/3572546).

With `WillPopScope` you can detect a possible change in route (pop) before it occurs and determine if it should be allowed or declined. If you simply want to carry out an action after pop, it can be done by overriding `onDispose`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I need to persist some data before onDispose is finished and it's not working. What do you suggest? .... Never mind RouteObserver is what I needed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Web part use below code to detect user active or not

```
 if (kIsWeb) {
      EasyLoading.init();
      window.addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
      window.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
    } else {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    }
```