# How to know when the user press to back to the page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making an app in flutter and I created a feature that I need to know when the user press to back to the page.
How can I do this in flutter?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if the user leaves the current page in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038560/detect-if-the-user-leaves-the-current-page-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget you need is `WillPopScope`. Wrap your scaffold with it and use the property `onWillPop` to do what you need. Here is an example:

```
class Hello extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Hi'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text('Hello'),
        ),
      ),
      onWillPop: () async {
        _doWhateverIWant();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

DOCS: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Are you sure?'),
            content: Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    "NO",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),
                  ),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                child: OutlineButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    "YES",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),
                  ),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ) ??
        false;
  },
  child: Center(
    child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
);
```

Here is a example which handles back press event when user taps on back button and ask for a cofirmation before closing the app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `WillOnPopScope`? You can access what happens when you press the back button with WillOnPopScope.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) for easy cases or for more convenience the [back_button_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor) package