# How to override the didPopRoute()

Tags: flutter

I want to override the `didPopRoute()` function but does not seem to work. I tried the following and does not seem to work:

```
class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    }

    @override
    Future<bool> didPopRoute() {
        print('didPopRoute');
        return super.didPopRoute();
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: will be flagging this as duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if the user leaves the current page in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038560/detect-if-the-user-leaves-the-current-page-in-flutter)

Comment: I edited the question so that my goal is clearer. Thanks.

Comment: trying this on android??

Comment: Right now, yes on android. But I want it to work on iOS too.

Comment: this is will called for each observer when **system** informs the app that it needs to go back/back button is pressed, i guess ios doesn't support this

Comment: Oh you are right, iOS does not have the back button. But anyway, how to override this function successfully?