# How to calculate page stay duration in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I want to calculate every pages stay duration of my flutter app. The stay duration means from page becomes visible to page hide.

How do i do this?

Any idea might help me.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to capture the time at `initState` for stateful widgets, or under `build` method for stateless widgets, and compare it with the time on leave, as follows:

```
  late DateTime started;
  DateTime? ended;

  @override
  void initState() {
    started = DateTime.now();
    super.initState();
  }

  void onLeave() {
    ended = DateTime.now();
    if (ended != null) {
      var lapse = Duration(microseconds: ended!.microsecondsSinceEpoch-started.microsecondsSinceEpoch);
      print("Viewed page ${lapse.inSeconds} seconds");
    }
  }
```

To learn how to detect when the user moves away from the current page take a look at this answer:

[Detect if the user leaves the current page in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038560/detect-if-the-user-leaves-the-current-page-in-flutter)

Comment: If a page just implement by StatelessWidget, how to do it?

Comment: @user5549139, stateless widgets should start the timer under the build method, which is mostly called only when the page is presented (for other corner cases when the page is rebuild take a look at the docu: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this wrapper widget,

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => TrackWidgetLifeTime(
            child: Text("$index"),
            lifeTime: (spent) {
              log("I've spend ${spent.toString()}");
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TrackWidgetLifeTime extends StatefulWidget {
  const TrackWidgetLifeTime({super.key, this.lifeTime, required this.child});
  final Function(Duration spent)? lifeTime;

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<TrackWidgetLifeTime> createState() => _TrackWidgetLifeTimeState();
}

class _TrackWidgetLifeTimeState extends State<TrackWidgetLifeTime> {
  var stopwatch = Stopwatch();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    stopwatch.start();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (widget.lifeTime != null) widget.lifeTime!(stopwatch.elapsed);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

Comment: Stopwatch was my first thought, but i believe it is way too expensive for the current purpose...

Comment: You might be right. My first thought was using a timer. while OP just need life-time, dateTime seems better.

Comment: If a page just implement by  StatelessWidget, how to do it?

Comment: Don't know and don't hesitate to use StatefulWidget,