# What is the correct way to dispose() widgets when switching pages and keep the ability to use the app bars back button?

Tags: flutter

I have a widget that fetches a new camera preview image every n seconds.

The timer that triggers the `build()` is disposed in the `dispose()` function.

This widget is on my first page and when I `push()` to another page, the timer keeps running and fetches images in the background.

A solution would be to use `pushReplacement()` but then I have to implement all the back buttons in the app bar myself, because I loose the history step.

It looks like this was possible with `deactivate()` but stopped working after a flutter upgrade in 2020 (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50147).

Am I missing something here, or is this the proper way to handle such cases (using pushReplacment and implementing all back buttons myself).

Here's a small example flutter project that illustrates my "problem":

https://github.com/vindolin/timerdispose

Edit: now I noticed that this solution only works for the back button in the appBar but the physical Android back button now closes my app because pushReplacement() replaced the history step.

Edit: I solved the problem with the follow up pages closing the app by wrapping them into a `WillPopScope`.

Comment: Maybe you should try taking a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/focus_detector.

Comment: You could also use the RouteAware in your page state, overriding the "didPush" and "didPopNext" functions. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66227393/9210158

Comment: @DanielPossamai I tried RouteAware but that doesn't seem to work, didPush/didPop... never fired.

Focus Detector seems to work good though, at least on my test example.
I will have to undo all the pushReplacementWillPopScope stuff and try it in the real app tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used a forked version of the focus_detector package as suggested by @DanielPossamai and it seems to work perfect.

My widget is observing onVisibilityLost/onVisibilityGained to start/stop the timer.

In this fork I changed the default updateInterval from 500ms to Duration.zero to make it more responsive: https://github.com/vindolin/focus_detector.