# how could I change the modes of flutter app with the mode of the mobile itself?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

how could I change the modes of flutter app with the mode of the mobile itself?
is there any available way to make this ?

Comment: What do you mean with mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay since you want to change your apps theme according to the user's current theme you have to:

1. Create a class that defines both the themes:
   Here is a link of one of my recent projects where I am using both dark and light themes :

class CustomTheme {

```
  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(

      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: CustomColors.coral,
          foregroundColor: Colors.grey.shade700),
      colorScheme: ColorScheme(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primary: CustomColors.coral,
          onPrimary: CustomColors.coral,
          secondary: CustomColors.babyPink,
          ),
      )),


static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primary: CustomColors.onBackground,
          onPrimary: CustomColors.onBackground,
          secondary: CustomColors.background,
          onSecondary: CustomColors.background,
          error: CustomColors.errorColor,
          onError: CustomColors.onErrorColor,
          background: CustomColors.background,
          onBackground: CustomColors.onBackground,
          surface: CustomColors.coral,
          onSurface: CustomColors.onBackground)),
```

2. Then specify your theme in the main.dart file

   MaterialApp(

   ```
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      theme: CustomTheme.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: CustomTheme.darkTheme,
      home: const SplashScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
   ```
3. Then use these themes wherever you want, so if you have a container then you can say

   color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,

Checkout one of my apps where I am using both themes

https://github.com/MayurSMahajan/FrontendSIH/tree/main/daemon/lib

Answer (score 0):

If by mode you mean Orientation, for instance Portrait mode to Landscape mode, then checkout this answer here, it might help you:

[How to detect orientation change in layout in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815014/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-flutter)

Or directly checkout flutter docs :
https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/orientation/

Comment: no i mean light and dark mode