# How to show list image like zalo in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-image

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBvIP.png)

How to show list image like zalo in flutter

Comment: I want the list of photos to be displayed by resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Staggred Grid View to display the images based on their resolution

Package Link: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Refer this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50778411/10970871) for more precise information

Comment: Milan Surelia thank you i will try it